# Sieve of Sundaram for Project Euler 7: Python implementation slower than C++ and R

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, primes, comparative-review

A friend of mine recently started learning R, and she complained to me that R is very slow. She was working on [Project Euler Problem 7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7), which asks for the value of the 10001st prime number. For comparison, I decided to write the exact same program in C++ (which I use most frequently), R (which I do not use regularly, but used for comparison), and Python (because I wanted to advise her to switch her learning from R to Python).

The program follows these steps:

1. Find the upper bound on the Nth prime.
2. Fill a prime number sieve ([Sieve of Sundaram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram)) large enough to capture the upper bound.
3. Count the primes in the prime number sieve until the Nth prime is found.

To my surprise, the Python solution was significantly slower than the R version. Here are the results from `time` for the three implementations:

- C++: real 0.002s, user 0.001s, sys 0.001s
- R: real 2.239s, user 2.065s, sys 0.033s
- Python: real 13.588s, user 13.566s, sys 0.025s

I tried using numpy arrays instead of lists, but to little effect.

I would appreciate an explanation of why the Python implementation is so slow relative to the other two. I would also appreciate tips on how to use lists in R and Python more efficiently. Is there a better way to do this?

C++:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int N = 10001;

int main()
{
  int max = floor(N*(log(N) + log(log(N))));
  vector<bool> marked(max/2, false);
  for (size_t i = 1; i < marked.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      size_t m = i + j + 2*i*j;
      if (m < marked.size()) {
        marked[m] = true;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  int count = 1;
  for (size_t m = 1; m < marked.size(); m++) {
    if (not marked[m]) count++;
    if (count == N) {
      cout << 2*m + 1 << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

R:

```
n <- 10001
max <- n*(log(n) + log(log(n)))
marked <- vector(mode="logical", length=max/2)
for (i in 1:length(marked)) {
  for (j in 1:i) {
    m <- i + j + 2*i*j
    if (m > length(marked)) break
    marked[m] <- T
  }
}
count <- 1
for (i in 1:length(marked)) {
  if (!marked[i]) count <- count + 1
  if (count == n) {
    print(2*i + 1)
    break
  }
}
```

Python:

```
from math import log

n = 10001
max = n*(log(n) + log(log(n)))
marked = [False] * int(max/2)
for i in range(1, len(marked)):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        m = i + j + 2*i*j
        if m > len(marked):
            break
        marked[m] = True
count = 0
for i in range(0, len(marked)):
  if not marked[i]:
      count += 1
  if count == n:
      print 2*i + 1
      break
```

Comment: Rather than trying to do three code reviews in on question, I have edited the title and tags to focus on the Python performance question. You may wish to ask separate questions about the C++ and R implementations.

Comment: In the C++ version, j goes from 1 to i, while in the R version j goes from 1 to length (marked).

Comment: @200_success, Thanks, that is a much better title.

Comment: @mjolka, I fixed the sloppy mistake in the R version. The code now runs in about half the time. I'm still curious as to why R beats Python here.

Comment: Was it entirely unexpected that python is slower than C++?

Comment: @ddriver The surprise was that Python was slower than R. If you scroll down to Veedrac's answer, you'll see something really suprising: using vector<int> instead of vector<bool>, the C++ solution can be even slower than an optimized version using NumPy!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**TL;DR: Just use PyPy; it gets you to about 10x the time of C++. If you really want to use CPython, a lot of clever optimizations (not algorithm changes) gets you as fast as PyPy and then using Numpy gets you close to C++ (2x the time).**

---

The first thing of note is that your Python code is broken:

```
    if m > len(marked):
        break
```

Remember that Python is 0-indexed. What about when `m == len(marked)`?

So that's the first thing to fix. Going from the top, I'd do the
translation so:

```
from math import log

n = 10001                              n <- 10001
maximum = n * (log(n) + log(log(n)))   max <- n*(log(n) + log(log(n)))
marked = [False] * int(maximum // 2)   marked <- vector(mode="logical", length=max/2)
for i in range(1, len(marked)+1):      for (i in 1:length(marked)) {
    for j in range(1, i+1):              for (j in 1:i) {
        m = i + j + 2*i*j                  m <- i + j + 2*i*j
        if m > len(marked): break          if (m > length(marked)) break
        marked[m-1] = True                 marked[m] <- T
                                         }
                                       }
count = 1                              count <- 1
for i in range(1, len(marked)+1):      for (i in 1:length(marked)) {
    if not marked[i-1]: count += 1       if (!marked[i]) count <- count + 1
    if count == n:                       if (count == n) {
        print(2*i + 1)                     print(2*i + 1)
        break                              break
                                         }
                                       }
```

This is as *direct* a mapping as possible; instead of changing the comparison
I just shifted the index when indexing. This isn't *idiomatic*, but it's direct.
It's largely the same as your code, but it's correct. This matters when we go to
larger N, where your code fails. It's also Python 3 compatible simply by using
`print` with brackets.

Let's time them:

```
$ time Rscript r.r
[1] 104743
Rscript r.r  1.59s user 0.78s system 99% cpu 2.375 total

$ time python2 p.py
104743
python2 p.py  12.88s user 0.00s system 100% cpu 12.873 total

$ time python3 p.py
104743
python3 p.py  0.16s user 0.00s system 98% cpu 0.163 total

$ # A faster, very compatible Python interpreter
$ time pypy p.py   
104743
pypy p.py  0.04s user 0.01s system 98% cpu 0.051 total

$ time pypy3 p.py
104743
pypy3 p.py  0.05s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.054 total
```

So there we have it. Python is over an order of magnitude faster on 75% of
interpreters, and under an order of magnitude slower in the worst case...

But why is it so slow with `python2`? `line_profiler` is a good utility:

```
import line_profiler
profiler = line_profiler.LineProfiler()

def main():
    # ... the code ...

profiler.enable()
profiler.add_function(main)
main()
profiler.print_stats()
```

Giving:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     4                                           def main():
     5         1          271    271.0      0.0      from math import log
     6                                           
     7         1            1      1.0      0.0      n = 10001
     8         1           22     22.0      0.0      maximum = n * (log(n) + log(log(n)))
     9         1          373    373.0      0.0      marked = [False] * int(maximum // 2)
    10     57160        37122      0.6      0.3      for i in range(1, len(marked)+1):
    11    188523      8444200     44.8     62.9          for j in range(1, i+1):
    12    188355       118260      0.6      0.9              m = i + j + 2*i*j
    13    188355      4672922     24.8     34.8              if m > len(marked): break
    14    131364        75962      0.6      0.6              marked[m-1] = True
    15                                           
    16                                           
    17         1            1      1.0      0.0      count = 1
    18     52371        25618      0.5      0.2      for i in range(1, len(marked)+1):
    19     52371        28393      0.5      0.2          if not marked[i-1]: count += 1
    20     52371        26003      0.5      0.2          if count == n:
    21         1           60     60.0      0.0              print(2*i + 1)
    22         1          329    329.0      0.0              break
```

So our most likely offending line is:

```
11    188523      8444200     44.8     62.9          for j in range(1, i+1):
```

On Python 2 there is both `range` and `xrange`. Using

```
for i in range(...):
```

will generate a list of numbers and then loop over them, whereas

```
for i in xrange(...):
```

will just increment i as wanted each time. This is often *much* faster. So let's add:

```
# Set range to xrange on Python 2
try:
    range = xrange
except NameError:
    pass
```

to the top of the script and retime:

```
$ time python2 p.py
104743
python2 p.py  0.09s user 0.00s system 96% cpu 0.090 total

$ time python3 p.py
104743
python3 p.py  0.16s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.161 total

$ time pypy p.py   
104743
pypy p.py  0.04s user 0.00s system 93% cpu 0.050 total

$ time pypy3 p.py
104743
pypy3 p.py  0.04s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.054 total
```

Yup. CPython is much improved.

So how would we make the code *good*? First you can transform the `i+j+2ij`
calculation to directly use a stepping range:

```
step = 2*i + 1
for m in range(i+step-1, i+i*step, step):
    if m >= len(marked):
      break

    marked[m] = True
```

Then you can just do a slice assignment:

```
for i in range(1, len(marked)+1):
    step = 2*i + 1
    marked[i+step-1::step] = [True] * len(marked[i+step-1::step])
```

and you can immediately see that you can stop when...

```
    if i+step-1 >= len(marked):
        break
```

This leads to calculating the bound in the `for` loop itself.
`step = 2*i + 1`, so `i+step-1 = i+(2*i+1)-1 = 3*i`, so we should
stop before `len(marked)//3`:

```
for i in range(1, len(marked)//3):
    step = 2*i + 1
    marked[i+step-1::step] = [True] * len(marked[i+step-1::step])
```

The `count` part can use `enumerate`:

```
count = 1
for i, mark in enumerate(marked, 1):
    if not mark:
        count += 1

    if count == n:
        print(2*i + 1)
        break
```

I suggest inverting the `True/False` in the array to make this simpler,
and then you can just do `count += mark`. Why? Well, it lets us use
`itertools.accumulate` on Python 3:

```
for i, count in enumerate(accumulate(marked), 1):
    if count+1 == n:
        print(2*i + 1)
        break
```

You might also think `len(marked[i+step-1::step])` is wasteful, since
it's generating a new array each time: it is!
It's still really fast, but Jaime's solution is better... except it
involves risky math steps. How could we get the best of both?

Well, remember how in Python 3 `range` is a fancy "pseudo-list" and
doesn't build a real list? Python 3's `range` can be *sliced*, too.
We just need to build a range the same length as the list and slice
that instead. This is actually slower on CPython (the one invoked
as `python3`) for normal-sized lists because CPython's list slices
are *really fast*, but on PyPy the overheads of the `range` version
are optimized out:

```
from itertools import accumulate
from math import log

n = 1000001
maximum = n * (log(n) + log(log(n)))
marked = [True] * int(maximum // 2)

slice_proxy = range(len(marked))
for i in range(1, len(marked)//3):
    step = 2*i + 1
    marked[i+step-1::step] = [False] * len(slice_proxy[i+step-1::step])

for i, count in enumerate(accumulate(marked), 1):
    if count+1 == n:
        print(2*i + 1)
        break
```

(Note the **much larger `n`**)

Times *without* `slice_proxy`:

```
$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  5.57s user 0.01s system 100% cpu 5.576 total

$ time pypy3 p.py  
15485867
pypy3 p.py  3.58s user 0.08s system 100% cpu 3.654 total
```

Times *with* `slice_proxy`:

```
$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  5.94s user 0.02s system 100% cpu 5.949 total

$ time pypy3 p.py  
15485867
pypy3 p.py  2.52s user 0.06s system 100% cpu 2.585 total
```

Then just wrap the whole thing in a `main` function, because local
variables are faster than global ones:

```
from itertools import accumulate
from math import log

def main():
    # ...

main()
```

Times:

```
$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  4.74s user 0.02s system 100% cpu 4.754 total

$ time pypy3 p.py  
15485867
pypy3 p.py  2.40s user 0.06s system 100% cpu 2.456 total
```

But wait! We dropped the end point!

```
for i in range(1, len(marked)//3):
    step  = 2*i + 1
    start = i+step-1
    stop  = 2*i*(i+1)
    marked[start:stop:step] = [False] * len(slice_proxy[start:stop:step])
```

This is important on PyPy; on CPython it's about the same speed:

```
$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  4.88s user 0.01s system 100% cpu 4.890 total

$ time pypy3 p.py  
15485867
pypy3 p.py  1.44s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 1.461 total
```

It's not really faster on CPython because the *number* of things you do tends to be more important
than *what* you do, simply from interpreter overhead.

---

We know it's way faster on CPython, but how does this compare to the original version on PyPy
(once stuck inside a `main` function)?

```
from math import log

def main():
    n = 1000001
    maximum = n * (log(n) + log(log(n)))
    marked = [False] * int(maximum // 2)

    for i in range(1, len(marked)+1):
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            m = i + j + 2*i*j

            if m > len(marked):
              break

            marked[m-1] = True

    count = 1
    for i in range(1, len(marked)+1):
        if not marked[i-1]:
            count += 1

        if count == n:
            print(2*i + 1)
            break

main()
```

Times:

```
$ time pypy p.py
15485867
pypy p.py  0.83s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 0.851 total

$ time pypy3 p.py
15485867
pypy3 p.py  0.78s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.790 total
```

Interestingly, **the original is significantly faster on PyPy**. This implies
that unless you want a code base optimized for both CPython *and* PyPy, some
of these optimizations (like `slice_proxy`) just aren't needed.

---

But, eh, what if this isn't fast enough?

Eh?

Well, let's quickly draw the things we're setting. `T` are the parts we set. `.` is the part we would set
if not for the `:end:` optimization.

```
index:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
  i=1         T        .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .
  i=2                  T              T              .              .              .              .
  i=3                           T                    T                    T                    .
  i=4                                    T                          T                          T
  i=5                                             T                                T
  i=6                                                      T                                      T
  i=7                                                               T
  i=8                                                                        T
  i=9                                                                                 T
  i=10                                                                                         T
  i=11                                                                                                  T
```

We're doing `i=1` then `i=2` then `i=3`, etc. From `i² ≈ len(marked)` onwards, though, there aren't many
things set each run. We end up moving back-and-forth in the array a lot, spending more time "seeking" in
memory than actually setting items. Consider, though, this decomposition:

```
index:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
  i=1         1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10
  i=2                  1              2              3              4              5              6
  i=3                           1                    2                    3                    4
  i=4                                    1                          2                          3
  i=5                                             1                                2
  i=6                                                      1                                      2
  i=7                                                               1
  i=8                                                                        1
  i=9                                                                                 1
  i=10                                                                                         1
  i=11                                                                                                  1
```

For low numbers, `1`, `2`, `3`, `...` this hits *a lot* of those later values. We can then split the work into
an upper part:

```
  i=1         T        .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .
  i=2                  T              T              .              .              .              .
  i=3                           T                    T                    T                    .
  i=4                                    T                          T                          T
  i=5                                             T                                T
```

and a lower part:

```
  i=6                                                      1                                      2
  i=7                                                               1
  i=8                                                                        1
  i=9                                                                                 1
  i=10                                                                                         1
  i=11                                                                                                  1
```

This *sets the same values*, but does so in a different order.

Here's the code:

```
from itertools import accumulate
from math import log

def main():
    n = 1000001
    maximum = n * (log(n) + log(log(n)))
    marked = [True] * int(maximum // 2)

    slice_proxy = range(len(marked))
    for i in range(1, int(len(marked)**0.5)):
        step  = 2*i + 1
        start = 3*i
        stop  = 2*i*(i+1)
        marked[start:stop:step] = [False] * len(slice_proxy[start:stop:step])

    i += 1
    start_step  = 2*i + 1
    start_start = 3*i
    step = 3
    for start in range(start_start, len(marked), start_step):
        marked[start::step] = [False] * len(slice_proxy[start::step])
        step += 2

    for i, count in enumerate(accumulate(marked), 1):
        if count+1 == n:
            print(2*i + 1)
            break

main()
```

How fast is it?

```
$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  1.53s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 1.538 total

$ time pypy3 p.py  
15485867
pypy3 p.py  1.26s user 0.06s system 100% cpu 1.319 total
```

CPython improves a lot with this, although PyPy doesn't really improve. This makes sense: you do a lot
fewer operations but each operation is more complicated. Since CPython has a really fast implementation
under the hood but a really slow interpreter, fewer operations is important. PyPy, however, is bound
by the size of the operations themselves.

Of course, for PyPy you'd want to modify the "original" code:

```
from math import log

def main():
    n = 1000001
    maximum = n * (log(n) + log(log(n)))
    marked = [True] * int(maximum // 2)

    for i in range(1, int(len(marked)**0.5)):
        step  = 2*i + 1
        start = 3*i
        stop  = 2*i*(i+1)

        if stop > len(marked):
            stop = len(marked)

        for m in range(start, stop, step):
            marked[m] = False

    i += 1
    start_step  = 2*i + 1
    start_start = 3*i
    step = 3
    for start in range(start_start, len(marked), start_step):
        for m in range(start, len(marked), step):
            marked[m] = False

        step += 2

    count = 1
    for i in range(1, len(marked)+1):
        if marked[i-1]:
            count += 1

        if count == n:
            print(2*i + 1)
            break

main()
```

Which gives

```
$ time pypy p.py
15485867
pypy p.py  0.65s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 0.672 total

$ time pypy3 p.py
15485867
pypy3 p.py  0.61s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.625 total
```

The difference is obviously much less, but it exists. This is probably
due to improvements in memory locality. It actually turns out that just
terminating the range with `len(marked)//3` gets you almost to this
point, so the optimization, IMHO, isn't worth it.

Sadly, CPython still trails the *first* version on PyPy. Janne Karila gave a good suggestion in the comments for speeding up CPython. The key part is to use `itertools` (or `filter`) to apply a filter and `islice` to do the counting. The large advantage comes from the iteration and counting being done inside C routines.

I went with [`compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) from Python 3.1 and Janne Karila's use of `islice` to get the wanted element:

```
primes = compress(range(3, int(maximum), 2), marked)
print(next(islice(primes, n-2, None)))
```

Timings are really good:

```
$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  0.58s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.598 total
```

This is (negligibly) faster than PyPy!

---

But, eh, but... but...

*What if this isn't fast enough?*

Eh?

Well, that's what Numpy is for. Numpy is Python's fast array library.

```
from math import log
import numpy

def main():

    n = 1000001
    maximum = n * (log(n) + log(log(n)))
    marked = numpy.ones(int(maximum // 2), dtype=bool)

    for i in range(1, int(len(marked)**0.5)):
        step  = 2*i + 1
        start = 3*i
        stop  = 2*i*(i+1)
        marked[start:stop:step] = False

    i += 1
    start_step  = 2*i + 1
    start_start = 3*i
    step = 3
    for start in range(start_start, len(marked), start_step):
        marked[start::step] = False
        step += 2

    accumulated = numpy.add.accumulate(marked)
    [where] = numpy.where(accumulated+1 == n)
    print(2 * where[0] + 3)

main()
```

This also works on Python 2. Unfortunately PyPy doesn't (yet)
have an easy Numpy port. Even so, the times:

```
$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  0.23s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 0.252 total

$ time python2 p.py
15485867
python2 p.py  0.17s user 0.02s system 98% cpu 0.196 total
```

C++ with this N takes:

```
$ g++ -O3 c.cpp -o c; time ./c
15485867
./c  0.06s user 0.00s system 96% cpu 0.065 total
```

Neat, but we're still not done. One slow part is

```
accumulated = numpy.add.accumulate(marked)
[where] = numpy.where(accumulated+1 == n)
print(2 * where[0] + 3)
```

It turns out that Numpy's `count_nonzero` is *really fast*, so let's try capitalizing on that with what amounts to a binary search. There are similarities to [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect):

```
# I can't think of a good name...
def count_nonzero_sorted(array, count):
    # We always assume the count is achievable
    if array.shape[0] == 1:
        return 0

    # Split the array in two
    midpoint = len(array) // 2
    first_half = array[:midpoint]
    second_half = array[midpoint:]

    first_counts = numpy.count_nonzero(first_half)

    # If the counts in the first half is greater
    # than the wanted index, check that half
    if first_counts >= count:
        return count_nonzero_sorted(first_half, count)

    # else check the other half and offset the result
    return midpoint + count_nonzero_sorted(second_half, count-first_counts)
```

This gives

```
# compress sieve
where = count_nonzero_sorted(marked, n-1)
print(2 * where + 3)
```

and timings of just

```
$ time python2 p.py
15485867
python2 p.py  0.10s user 0.01s system 97% cpu 0.116 total

$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  0.16s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.167 total
```

On Python 2 that's half the speed of C++! Vectorization is a wonderful thing.

It would be interesting how many of these optimizations can apply to R.
A preliminary guess puts the time required for the original R code to run as about 7 hours.

What should you take away from this?

1. PyPy is **really, really fast**. The *original code* (after the
   bug is fixed) takes only 0.7-0.9 seconds, or a tenth the speed of C++.

   PyPy thus ends up, by my guess, about 10000 times as fast
   as the implementation of R that I have available (for this task).
2. Optimizing PyPy is possible but it's hard; the optimized PyPy was
   only a little faster than the original PyPy code at 0.6-0.7s.
   This is because the JIT gives you most optimizations for free.
3. CPython has sharp corners (`range` vs `xrange`) but Python 3 takes
   some of these problems away by default. Once you handle this, CPython
   is an order of magnitude faster than R on this code.
4. CPython *can* be *forced* to go fast *if you know what you are doing*.
   When forced it became a touch faster than PyPy.
5. CPython is ridiculously fast when Numpy is used; getting to half the speed
   of C++.

---

I thought to check how [a traditional sieve](https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/9700563) compares against this:

```
import sys
from itertools import compress, islice
from math import log

def main():
    n = 1000001
    maximum = int(n * (log(n) + log(log(n))))
    maxidx = maximum//2
    sieve = [True] * maxidx # 2, 3, 5, 7... might be prime

    j = 0
    for i in range(1, int(maxidx**0.5)+1):
        j += 4*i

        if sieve[i]:
            step = 2*i + 1
            sieve[j::step] = [False] * -(-(maxidx-j) // step)

    # compress sieve
    print(next(islice(compress(range(1, maximum, 2), sieve), n-1, None)))

main()
```

and the PyPy version:

```
import sys
from itertools import compress, islice
from math import log

def main():
    n = 1000001
    maximum = int(n * (log(n) + log(log(n))))
    maxidx = maximum//2
    sieve = [True] * maxidx # 2, 3, 5, 7... might be prime

    j = 0
    for i in range(1, int(maxidx**0.5)+1):
        j += 4*i

        if sieve[i]:
            for k in range(j, maxidx, 2*i + 1):
                sieve[k] = False

    # compress sieve
    count = 1
    for i in range(1, maxidx):
        count += sieve[i]

        if count == n:
            print(2*i + 1)
            break

main()
```

and the Numpy version:

```
import numpy
from math import log

def count_nonzero_sorted(array, count):
    # We always assume the count is achievable
    if array.shape[0] == 1:
        return 0

    midpoint = len(array) // 2
    first_half = array[:midpoint]
    second_half = array[midpoint:]

    first_counts = numpy.count_nonzero(first_half)

    if first_counts >= count:
        return count_nonzero_sorted(first_half, count)

    return midpoint + count_nonzero_sorted(second_half, count-first_counts)

def main():
    n = 1000001
    maximum = int(n * (log(n) + log(log(n))))
    maxidx = maximum//2
    sieve = numpy.ones(maxidx, dtype=bool) # 2, 3, 5, 7... might be prime

    j = 0
    for i in range(1, int(maxidx**0.5)+1):
        j += 4*i

        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[j::2*i + 1] = False

    # compress sieve
    where = count_nonzero_sorted(sieve, n)
    print(2 * where + 1)

main()
```

Timings:

```
$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  0.40s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.415 total

$ time pypy3 p.py 
15485867
pypy3 p.py  0.36s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.368 total

$ # Numpy versions
$ time python2 p.py 
15485867
python2 p.py  0.07s user 0.01s system 97% cpu 0.075 total

$ time python3 p.py
15485867
python3 p.py  0.12s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.124 total
```

Sorry, Sieve of Sundaram, you're not that great after all. :P

And, heck, that Python 2 version is way too fast.

---

*Note: I made a mistake previously in comparing `vector<bool>` to `vector<int>`; I should have compared it to `vector<uint8_t>` instead. It turns out that the difference is actually relatively minor (30-40%) and although significant it isn't nearly the factor-of-4 difference from before.*

Comment: This is the best response that I've seen on CodeReview so far. I have learned a great deal about how to improve my Python style and use of lists. All of this is new to me. Thank you for the Herculean effort that you put into writing this.

Comment: I get a nice speedup on Python 3, starting from the "here's the code" version, by initializing `marked = list(range(1, int(maximum // 2) + 1))` and replacing the last loop by `i = next(islice(filter(None, marked), n-2, None))`

Comment: @JanneKarila Thanks; I've incorporated (and built on) this suggestion.

Comment: Nice answer. As far as I can tell, `len(mark)` doesn't change at all. Why not put in in a variable instead of calculating it at every loop?

Comment: @EricDuminil `len` on an array is effectively just an attribute lookup, and is unlikely to be expensive unless called *inside* the innermost loop.

Answer (score 10):

Explicit looping in Python is (very) slow, and you have a double loop, which isn't helping. Your inner loop is effectively setting to `True` a slice of `marked` of the form `marked[3*i+1::2*i+1]`, and you can take advantage of that to speed things up considerably. The only tricky part is figuring out how many items you have to set, to properly build the right hand side of the assignment. It is not hard to figure out that if you have a list with`len_` items, and you set every `step`-th item starting with `start`, you will in total set `ceil((len_-start) / step)` elements, which can be computed directly as `(len_-start-1)//step + 1`. Putting it all together:

```
from math import log
from itertools import repeat

n = 10001
max_ = n*(log(n) + log(log(n)))
len_ = int(max_/2)
marked = [False] * len_
for i in range(1, len_):
    step = 2*i + 1
    start = step + i
    marked[start::step] = [True] * ((len_-start-1)//step+1)

count = 0
for i in range(0, len(marked)):
  if not marked[i]:
      count += 1
  if count == n:
      print 2*i + 1
      break
```

Which prints out the exact same value in a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 5):

The Python version isn't exactly the same as the C++ one.

C++:

> ```
>   if (m < marked.size()) {
>     marked[m] = true;
>   } else {
>     break;
>   }
> ```

Python:

> ```
> if m > len(marked):
>     break
> marked[m] = True
> ```

So we want to change part of the inner loop to this:

```
if m < len(marked):
    marked[m] = True
else:
    break
```

To speed it up, just [change `range` to `xrange`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Use_xrange_instead_of_range).

> When you call `range`, it creates a `list` containing so many number (`int`,
>   `long`, or `float`) objects. All of those objects are created at once, and
>   all of them exist at the same time. This can be a pain when the number
>   of numbers is large.
>
> `xrange`, on the other hand, creates *no* numbers immediately - only the
>   range object itself. Number objects are created only when you pull on
>   the generator, e.g. by looping through it.

```
from math import log

n = 10001
max = n*(log(n) + log(log(n)))
marked = [False] * int(max/2)
for i in xrange(1, len(marked)):
    for j in xrange(1, i + 1):
        m = i + j + 2*i*j
        if m < len(marked):
            marked[m] = True
        else:
            break
count = 0
for i in xrange(0, len(marked)):
    if not marked[i]:
        count += 1
    if count == n:
        print 2*i + 1
        break
```

On my machine: `0.15s user 0.01s system 97% cpu 0.162 total`.

Answer (score 2):

Although your main question has been answered,
all of these implementations have a common shortcoming:
no need to do the `count == n` check if `count` hasn't changed.

Instead of this:

> ```
>   if (!marked[i]) count <- count + 1
>   if (count == n) {
>     print(2*i + 1)
>     break
>   }
> ```

This is better:

```
  if (!marked[i]) {
    count <- count + 1
    if (count == n) {
      print(2*i + 1)
      break
    }
  }
```

About the C++ implementation:

- [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is considered bad practice
- `!marked[i]` is more common (and thus more natural) than `not marked[i]`
- Since the size of `marked` is decided in advance, it might be interesting to try a boolean array for it instead of a vector

About R, don't dismiss the language so easily.
For project Euler, it might not be a great choice,
but it's an excellent choice for many other things.
Make sure to consider the bigger picture first!

Comment: `vector<bool>` is special cased to a bit vector; I'd assume (naïvely perhaps) that this will end up more important than any gains from having a "raw" array.